# Formula for $q$-expansion of weight 2 modular forms

Tags: reference-request, power-series, modular-forms

Is there a general formula for finding the $q$-expansion of weight 2 modular forms?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Maybe it would be helpful if you showed some of your working?

Comment: Did you spot anything?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is too deep and important to have a simple, tidy solution! About the best one can get is the approach described in Loic Merel's article "Universal Fourier expansions of modular forms".

EDIT: if you want tables for a specific weight and level, the [LMFDB](http://lmfdb.org/) (L-functions and Modular Forms Database) is the place to go.

Comment: Thanks. If I was looking for those of a specific level (say 11) would there be a place to look e.g., some sort of table/reference?